# Using RandomGen in newsynth

Tags: haskell, random-seed

I'm new to Haskell and am trying to get some code up and running on a bit of a tight schedule, which is why I'm doing something more complicated than the absolute basics. I'm using the package newsynth and would like to use the function `root_of_negative_one` ([documentation](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/newsynth-0.4.0.0/docs/Quantum-Synthesis-Diophantine.html), [source](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/newsynth-0.4.0.0/src/Quantum/Synthesis/Diophantine.hs)). In GHCi, I run the following commands:

```
Prelude> import Quantum.Synthesis.Diophantine
Prelude Quantum.Synthesis.Diophantine> :set -package random
Prelude Quantum.Synthesis.Diophantine> import System.Random
Prelude Quantum.Synthesis.Diophantine System.Random> let g = getStdGen
Prelude Quantum.Synthesis.Diophantine System.Random> let x = root_of_negative_one g 5
```

to try to get a square root of -1 mod 5. GHCi returns:

```
<interactive>:7:9: error:
    • No instance for (RandomGen (IO StdGen))
        arising from a use of ‘root_of_negative_one’
    • In the expression: root_of_negative_one g 5
      In an equation for ‘x’: x = root_of_negative_one g 5
```

I know that `root_of_negative_one` needs an input of type RandomGen but I seem to have not understood the RandomGen documentation well enough to execute this. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: You could use pure function [mkStdGen](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/random-1.1/docs/System-Random.html#v:mkStdGen) which takes an Int seed and returns a generator. Alternatively you can also use [mkTFGen](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/tf-random-0.5/docs/System-Random-TF.html#v:mkTFGen), which is similar but uses a more recent pseudo-random number generation algorithm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`root_of_negative_one` needs a `StdGen`, but `getStdGen` is an `IO StdGen`. You need to do `g <- getStdGen` instead of `let g = getStdGen`.

Comment: I see. When I do that, GHCi returns ```Incomplete```. Is there some deeper issue going on with the packages?

Comment: @zjs That's normal for a `StepComp`. Take a look at [its documentation](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/newsynth-0.4.0.0/docs/Quantum-Synthesis-StepComp.html#t:StepComp), in particular the "Run functions".